# ng-boilerplate LESS files are not compiling to the CSS file in build directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, gruntjs, less, ngboilerplate

The CSS (from LESS) is not rendering or compiling in my ng-boilerplate app.

I'm creating an app using ng-boilerplate and rails using these tutorials [here](https://technpol.wordpress.com/2013/08/25/crud-application-with-angularjs-rails-twitter-bootstrap-and-ng-boilerplate-part-2/), and we've integrated a working rails server with the angular. The angular is working on any page... as in, we can use:

```
$scope.animal = "dogs"
```

and

```
<div> I like {{animal}}! </div>
```

to get

```
I like dogs!
```

However, the Less and CSS (which was copied and pasted from a functional ng-boilerplate app without rails where it worked and compiled from all the different directories just fine) is not compiling to the build directory nor rendering. In fact, in this new app (the one with the rails), not even the original css/less from the ng-boilerplate template will compile or render.

We tried using the following commands, as the tutorial suggested, which created weird nested build directories (a build inside the build inside the build) and didn't fix the problem.

```
cd public
ln -s ../build UI
```

Meanwhile, the UI folder is linked to the build folder using a symlink but...

The LESS (from different files in different directories) is all supposed to compile to one CSS file called ng-boilerplate.css (which it did in the original app without rails), and instead there's a file called ng-boilerplate-0.3.1.css, which is empty. I tried renaming that, but it re-renames itself back to the 0.3.1 one every time grunt builds it.

I'm using rails version 4.2.1 and ruby says it's 2.1.0p0.

Comment: better check the less code is there any error.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you have already found a solution, as I realise that this post is quite old. However, since this question appears reasonably highly when I was google searching, I felt it should have an answer.

When using ng-boilerplate, you need to be aware that, although it's compile process finds all of your JS files and makes nice compiled JS code, the same is not done for the LESS files in their build process. If you look in the directory 'src/app/less/' and view the 'main.less' file, you can see a small note mentioning that he would like to automate this process. Instead, it is at this point that you unfortunately need to manually import all of your LESS files.

The LESS way to import files is this for anybody who is unsure:

@import '../app/less/fileToImport.less'

The path can be relative or absolute.